# distinct value issue

Tags: xml

i have 2 xml file as below:

```
staff.xml
<staff>
  <person>
    <PID>1</PID>
    <name>John</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <PID>2</PID>
    <name>Rain</name>
  </person>
  <person>
    <PID>3</PID>
    <name>Bain</name>
  </person>
</staff>

fruit.xml
<fruit>
  <fruitname PID="1" >Apple<fruitname>
  <fruitname PID="1" >Orange<fruitname>
  <fruitname PID="2" >Orange<fruitname>
</fruit>
```

the code that i wrote was as below: and the output was a list of duplicate name.the problem now is i would want the name of the person that ate orange to be return once only instead of several times. is it possible to do something like return distinct-values($/name) or is there any other way that i can remove the duplicates?

```
for $s in doc("staff.xml")//person
for $f in doc("fruit.xml")//fruitname
where $s/PID=$f/@PID and $/f[@type="orange"]
return $s/name
```

i tried something like below,but it changes it to atomic value with no duplicate.but the thing is i need the out put as an element not atomic value.

```
  distinct-values(
    for $s in doc("staff.xml")//person
    for $f in doc("fruit.xml")//fruitname
    where $s/PID=$f/@PID and $/f[@type="orange"]
    return $s/name)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Use**:

```
for $pid in distinct-values(doc("fruit.xml")/*/*[@type eq 'orange']/@PID)
  return
    doc('staff.xml')/*/*[PID eq $pid][1]/name
```

Comment: lets say if i were to change the fruit.xml, the fruitname element i have remove the @type attribute and made the Orange as the fruitname value.now  how do i check the fruit to know whether it is an orange as the previous //fruitname[@type="orange"]  will not work now.

Comment: @setiasetia, If you do so many changes, then you have to ask a new question.

Answer (score 0):

You can even do it using an implicit join:

```
doc("staff.xml")//person[PID = doc("fruit.xml")//fruitname[@type="orange"]/@PID]
```

Answer (score 0):

Try this

```
for $i in doc('test')//fruit
   return $i/fruitname[(index-of(doc('test')//fruit/fruitname, .)[position() > 1])[1]]/string()
```

For the fruits.xml

```
<fruit>
    <fruitname PID="1" >Apple</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="1" >Orange</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="2" >Orange</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="3" >Pears</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="2" >Mango</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="1" >Apple</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="4" >Guava</fruitname>
    <fruitname PID="5" >Orange</fruitname>
</fruit>
```

the Xquery results

```
 Orange Apple
```

Try here: http://basex.org/products/live-demo/